# Kubernetes master node's date was updated. Certifactes have now expired?

Tags: kubernetes

I had an incorrect date set (by a few years) I've modified this but now I'm getting errors with some pods:

**kube-controller-manager-master**

> E0803 01:06:31.311871       1 leaderelection.go:234] error retrieving
>   resource lock kube-system/kube-controller-manager: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-controller-manager:
>   x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

**kube-scheduler-master**

> E0803 01:06:24.507668       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130:
>   Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid E0803
>   01:06:24.511785       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130:
>   Failed to list *v1beta1.ReplicaSet: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/replicasets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid E0803
>   01:06:24.532539       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130:
>   Failed to list *v1.Node: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/api/v1/nodes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid E0803
>   01:06:24.543719       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130:
>   Failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/apis/policy/v1beta1/poddisruptionbudgets?limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid E0803
>   01:06:24.547678       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130:
>   Failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/api/v1/replicationcontrollers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid E0803
>   01:06:24.554880       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:130:
>   Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: Get
>   https://192.168.0.33:6443/api/v1/persistentvolumes?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid E0803
>   01:06:24.559708       1 reflector.go:205]
>   k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:176: Failed to list
>   *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.0.33:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase%21%3DFailed%2Cstatus.phase%21%3DSucceeded&limit=500&resourceVersion=0:
>   x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to delete the whole cluster and start again, which I had to do now...